# CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + A to open hidden form

Tags: vb.net, keydown

I'am working on creating a shortcut keys to open a certain form, I have `KeyPreview = true` and I am using this code and it works great!

```
#Region "Shortcuts"
    Private Sub frmQueuing_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
            frmMain.show()
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region
```

However I tried to expand that code by adding Alt and Shift, it is not working now. I don't know why.

```
#Region "Shortcuts"
    Private Sub frmQueuing_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Alt AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
            frmMain.show()
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
#Region "Shortcuts"
    Private Sub frmQueuing_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If (e.Control  AndAlso e.Shift AndAlso e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.A) Then
            frmMain.show()
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region
```

these links will help you to understand differences between [KeyEventArgs.KeyCode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [KeyEventArgs.Alt Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Still not working. I don't know why? This is so weird.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.A And Control.ModifierKeys = (Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + Keys.Alt) Then
```